# XAML element binding between 2 files?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Suppose I have a two textboxes in the same XAML file. I want the input in textbox 2 to come from whatever I type in textbox 1.

That's simple enough (I think, correct me if I'm wrong):

```
Textbox x:name="TextBox1" Text="Your Text Here"
Textbox x:name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1, Path=Text}"
```

My lack of understanding arrives when I take TextBox2 and put it in another XAML file. TextBox2 no longer knows about TextBox1. Suppose TextBox1 is in a file called "File1.xaml" and TextBox2 is in a file called "File2.xaml". What additional information can I provide (and where) to keep this same simple link of elements alive?

Comment: Consider learning about MVVM and declarative data binding to view model objects in WPF. Your text boxes should not access each other directly - rather, they can be data-bound to the same variable (and changes will be reflected automatically at the framework level).

Comment: Thanks! I understand the idea of binding them to a variable, but I can't find a simple example of this happening at the most basic level. I was hoping with just two textboxes, this might be simple enough to evoke an answer that explains the concept to me.

Comment: Dean's answer seems about right. You might want to check the Channel9 videos that do an introduction to wpf. Trust me, you _really really_ want to separate your presentation later from your business logic layer and have a separate variable in a view model. This is fundamental to your understanding of WPF and even if it takes a few more hours to learn where you'll be learning instead of building it'll make your life a lot better in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want your `Window`s, `UserControl`s or `View`s in MVVM terminology to "know" about each other so you have two options...

1. Your Views are sharing the same `DataContext` which is their `ViewModel` and the two `TextBox`es are bound to the same public Property in that `ViewModel` (The `ViewModel` will have to support change notification).
2. Your `View`s have two different `DataContext`s (`ViewModel`s) and you use messaging to send the values of the two public Properties two `TextBox`es are bound to back and forth...

Here is what 2 would look like using one of the MVVM frameworks...

View 1:

```
DataContext="{Binding ViewModel1, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
...
Textbox x:name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding MyString1}"
```

ViewModel 1:

```
private string myString1;
public string MyString1
{
    get { return myString1; }
    set 
       { 
          myString1 = value; 
          NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.MyString1); 
          SendMessage(MessageTokens.MyString1, new NotificationEventArgs<string>
            ("Message", myString1));
       }
}
```

View 2:

```
DataContext="{Binding ViewModel2, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
...
Textbox x:name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding MyString2}"
```

ViewModel 2:

```
RegisterToReceiveMessages<string>(MessageTokens.MyString1, 
    (s, ea) => MyString2 = ea.Data);
...
private string myString2;
public string MyString2
{
    get { return myString2; }
    set 
       { 
          myString2 = value; 
          NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.MyString2);
       }
}
```